# Excel files are not being read when executing Selenium C# Scripts on Azure Releases

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some Selenium C# tests hosted on Azure which they need to look for the pre-built excel file in project tree, stored inside bin folder, to execute some file upload validation scenarios.

When they are executed locally these scenarios pass without any problem, but when it comes to be executed on the Azure they receive the following error.

```
invalid argument: File not found : D:\a\r1\a_Selenium_Tests\TestApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Files\SC003_CT014_ActiveEmployees.xlsx
```

The files do exists in the following path: ...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Files...

And the code I use to them is:

`string root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Files\\" + file;`

Do you know if there's a missing file configuration or building the filePath in another way?

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory.GetCurrentDirection()` returns the current **working** directory, not the folder in which the DLL file resides. The current working directory is a different thing. In your case, the current working directory is probably something like `D:\a\r1\`. Instead, you need to get the folder in which the test assembly resides:

```
var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^
var excelFilePath = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "Files", "SC003_CT014_ActiveEmployees.xlsx");
```

Note: Replace `GetType()` with `typeof(ClassName)` if you are executing your code from a static method, or you would like to specify a path to a different assembly than the one that is currently executing.